# Flex Mobile Text wrap around image

Tags: html, image, apache-flex, mobile

I'm attempting to create a component for a Flex Mobile application that allows me to have a image with text wrapped around it, as is very common in articles or blog posts. Using HTML, this could be accomplished with a tag such as:

`<image align='right' /> associated text...`

I've tried creating a s:TextArea, and setting it's text to a HTML string like this:

`StyleableTextField(textArea.textDisplay).htmlText = htmlString`

But this method does not seem to support images. I could use separate images and text components, but then the text would not wrap around the image the way I want.

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Did you have a question?  The Text Layout Framework (TLF) is designed for doing things like this, but I am not sure if it is supported on mobile.  The Flex Mobile Skins go out of their way to not use TLF due to performance considerations.

Answer (score 0):

This could be performed using [`TextFlow`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/TextFlow.html), appearing as:

> [image: text-flow]

Use [`TextConverter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/conversion/TextConverter.html) [`importToFlow()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/conversion/TextConverter.html#importToFlow%28%29) as the composer to assemble the html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;
            import flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow;

            private const text:String = "<img src='http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png' " +
                "align='right' width='138' height='48' />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, " +
                "consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sodales posuere elit nec convallis. " +
                "Vivamus lacinia consectetur tortor, in convallis diam ornare sit amet. " +
                "Morbi volutpat volutpat aliquet. Praesent hendrerit nibh et magna feugiat " +
                "laoreet. Maecenas congue rhoncus tincidunt. Aliquam libero dui, scelerisque " +
                "eu convallis at, consectetur vitae dolor. Nunc quis posuere tellus.";
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:RichEditableText editable="false"
                        selectable="true"
                        textFlow="{TextConverter.importToFlow(text, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT)}"
                        buttonMode="true"
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%" />

</s:Application>
```

Note that AIR also has [`StageWebView`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html), which uses the system web control provided by the device operating system.

Comment: It is worth nothing, as I stated in my comment on the post, that the Text Layout Framework is not included by default in a Flex Mobile project, and the default mobile Skins do not use the Text Layout Framework.  RichEditableText is not a mobile supported component.  He'll have to jump through some hoops to get this solution to work on mobile; and I have no idea how well it will perform.

Comment: Yeah, none of this is supported in Flex Mobile, and I don't want to degrade performance and increase the file size by trying to embed TLF. It seemed like such a simple thing that I am surprised it's not easily achieved with supported components. I guess I didn't miss an obvious simple solution.

Comment: Its use is discouraged, for sure; however, `StageWebView` is another option depending on the extent of your requirement.